# libgdx setup JAVA_HOME not set

Tags: java, libgdx

I have `JAVA_HOME` set as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65` and have added to my `PATH %JAVA_HOME%\bin`. When I run  `javac -version`, and echo `%JAVA_HOME%`, they all give me the correct information. However, when I run the libgdx setup app, it gives me the following error:
`ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.`

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, provide All PATH variable value here.

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 0):

Remove `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` from `PATH` variable. Which is located in starting.

Then save. Try `java -version` or `javac` or `javac -version`